# multiplying with a string variable

Tags: java

I have saved some user input using the code;

```
String message3 = console.nextLine();
```

Now I want to multiply the variable message3 by a fixed number (say 5.2)
and display that result on the console to the user again. message3 will always be a number

I have tried using the code:

```
String message4 = message3 * 3;
```

but it comes up with the error that: The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int. I know when I remove message3 and replace it with a number it works. So how do I get the variable message3 to multiply with another number? Do I have to rename message3? thanks

Comment: Do you want to repeat the string three times, or do you want to multiply a number, like a `double` ? ;)

Answer (score 6):

You will have to transform that String into a primitive number.

You can do that with

```
int integerNumber = Integer.parseInt(message3);
```

or

```
double doubleNumber = Double.parseDouble(message3);
```

If the string does not contain a convertable number, an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert the type first to make multiplication possible:

```
String message4 = Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(message3) * 3);
```

As a non-numeric type, the `*` operator does not have any meaning for `String`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `message3` to an integer to be valid for multiplication:

```
int result = Integer.parseInt(message3) * 3;
```

Then you can assign this to a string as follows:

```
String message4 = "" + result; // or just Integer.toString(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to first convert a string into integer. with java api you can acheive this using parseInt(String) or using Integer(wrapper class) constructor like below

```
  approach1
    String num="4";
     Integer.parseInt(num)*10;

   It throws Number format exception if the string is a non parsable int

  approach2
  String num="4";
   Integer i = new Integer(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input is a integer you can do this way:

```
String message3 = console.nextLine();
Integer myNumber = Integer.valueOf(message3) * 3;
```

or

```
int myNumber = Integer.parseInt(message3) * 3;
```

Use the appropiate type for the operation you want to do.